# en localhost xampp envia mail y en Hostinger nada

Tags: php

amigos un apoyo x favor, soy aprendiz de este lenguaje, y  el siguiente PHP trabaja bien en localhost con xampp y luego subido al servidor HOstinger no envia el email y aparece el error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'PHPMailer\src\Exception.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear:.:/PHPMailer/src') in
>   /home/u861627377/public_html/enviar_mail.php on line 6.

Tengo instalada la carpeta PHPmailer tambien.
Como debo configurar el path o que cambio realizar?
Gracias amigos.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer\src\Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer\src\SMTP.php';

//Reseteo variables.
$error = NULL;
//Comprobamos si esta definida el formulario y no es NULL.
if (isset($_POST["email"])){

$dato1 = TRIM($_POST['email']);
$tabla = "members";
require('conexion.php');

$ssql = ("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE  correo = '$dato1' ");
$resultado = mysqli_query($enlace,$ssql);
//echo "$dato1  ";
//echo "br    ";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0)
    {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
            //echo "$row[5]";

        try {
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            $mail->isSMTP(); // Usar SMTP
            //$mail->isMail();   

            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );

            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            //$mail->Host = "localhost";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // si es isSMTP() es true
            $mail->Username = "hccsolutions99@gmail.com";
            $mail->Password = "*******"; 
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
            //$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
            //$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
            //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';     // tls 587 o ssl 465 Habilita encriptacion
            $mail->Port = 587;    // Puerto SMTP 587 o 25 ok , 465 naca          
            //$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
            //$mail->SMTPSecure = false;


            $mail->Timeout = 30;
            //$mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
            $mail->From = "hccsolutions@gmail.com";  //remitente
            $mail->FromName = "SISCLOUD xxx";              // nombre remitente
            $mail->addAddress($row[4]); //destinatario
            //Dirección a la que responderá destinatario.
            //$mail->addReplyTo("hccsolutions99@gmail.com","Administrador");
            //BCC ->  incluir copia oculta de email enviado.
            //$mail->addBCC("copia@tudominio.com");
            //Enviar codigo HTML o texto plano.
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            //Titulo email.
            $mail->Subject = "Envio de Contraseña " ;
            //Cuerpo email con HTML.
            $mail->Body = "Tu contraseña es:   " . $row[5]; //. $row[5]; //Podrias personalizar mediante HTML y CSS :)
            // envio mail
            $mail->send();
            echo "El mensaje fue enviado";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'El mensaje no pudo ser enviado. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
    } else {
        echo 'Error Usuario NO registrado' ;
        echo "<br>";
        Echo "<a href='index.html'>Retornar</a>";

    }

} 

?>
```

Comment: Tu hostinger es gratuito? o es version premium? - creo que hay algunas cosas que tiene deshabilitado el hostinger gratuito.

Comment: he pagado amigo x 3 meses.

Comment: No sugiero que lo publiques aquí, pero tal vez te convenga correr el comando `phpinfo` y compartir aquí lo referente a la configuración de correo electrónico para verificar que estén habilitadas las librerías y puertos para enviar correo electrónico

Comment: ok amigo lo vere por ese lado tambien. Gracias

Comment: alguna otra propuesta amigos !